# Как считать данные из базы Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно считывать данные из Firebase. Работаю по документации, делаю вроде все так, но выводит 'Database Permission denied'.

```
package com.example.strike.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import stanford.androidlib.SimpleActivity;

public class LoginActivity extends SimpleActivity {
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("/animal/PLaNGFwshzOhzys2VhOP");

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value =  dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value is: " + databaseError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Правила

```
service cloud.firestore {

    match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
       allow read, write;
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Во первых: надо понимать что Fairbase предоставляет сейчас две базы данных Cloud Firestore и Realtime Database, обрати внимание с какой из них ты работаешь - в консоле и в коде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В коде ты работаешь с RealTime Database, а правила показал для другой базы - Cloud Firestore. Что бы заработало тебе надо создать RealTime Database в консоле FireBase, смотри на картинку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо менять код, но там тоже ничего сложного.